# AutoMapper flatten nested collections

Tags: c#, automapper

I try to figure out how to flatten a collection of Merchants, each containing a collection of Orders to a flat List of OrderViewModels.

Here my DTO:

```cs
public class Merchant
{
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

And Here's the view model:

```cs
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

My Goal is to flatten a **List<Merchant>** to a **List<OrderViewModel>** whereas the following test structure should result in 6 view models:

```cs
var myMerchants = new List<Merchant>
{
    new Merchant
    {
        MerchantName = "Merchant X",
        Orders = new List<Order>
        {
             new Order { OrderId = "Order 1"},
             new Order { OrderId = "Order 2"},
             new Order { OrderId = "Order 3"}
        }
    },
    new Merchant
    {
        MerchantName = "Merchant Y",
        Orders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order { OrderId = "Order 4"},
            new Order { OrderId = "Order 5"},
            new Order { OrderId = "Order 6"}
        }
    }
 };

 var models = Mapper.Map<List<OrderViewModel>>(myMerchants);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the cardinality of the root objects isn't 1:1, (i.e. 2 root `Merchants` need to map to 6 `OrderViewModels`), you may need to resort to a [custom `TypeConverter`](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters) and operate at the collection level, where you can use `.SelectMany` to do the flattening:

```
public class MyTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<IEnumerable<Merchant>, List<OrderViewModel>>
{
    public List<OrderViewModel> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null || context.IsSourceValueNull)
            return null;

        var source = context.SourceValue as IEnumerable<Merchant>;

        return source
            .SelectMany(s => s.Orders
              .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
              {
                  MerchantName = s.MerchantName,
                  OrderId = o.OrderId
              }))
              .ToList();
    }
}
```

Which you can then bootstrap:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Merchant>, List<OrderViewModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing<MyTypeConverter>();
```

And then mapped as such:

```
var models = Mapper.Map<List<OrderViewModel>>(myMerchants);
```

Answer (score 4):

An interesting finding is that, only do the below is enough to achieve the goal without automapper.

```
var models = myMerchants.SelectMany(s => s.Orders.Select(o => new OrderViewModel { MerchantName = s.MerchantName, OrderId = o.OrderId })).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but thought would be helpful for newer versions.

I am using .Net core 2 with automapper. I prefer to do the ProjectTo extension of queryable

```
queryable
   .SelectMany(outterClass => outterClass.innerList)
   .AsQueryable()
   .ProjectTo<OutterClassDto>();
```

Then, configure like so:

```
config.CreateMap<OuterClass, OuterClassDto>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to combine SelectMany with AutoMapper and do the mapping for each item in the flattened collection. You need two mappings for this Merchant -> OrderViewModel and Order -> OrderViewModel

```
var models = myMerchants.SelectMany(s => s.Orders.Select(o => 
{
    var mappedItem = Mapper.Map<OrderViewModel>(s);
    Mapper.Map(o, mappedItem);
    return mappedItem;
})).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Automapper ConvertUsing() also accepts a Func.

```
 CreateMap<IEnumerable<Merchant>, IEnumerable<OrderViewModel>>()
     .ConvertUsing((src, desc) => src.SelectMany(m => m.Orders,
     (m, o) => new OrderViewModel
     {
         m.MerchantName,
         o.OrderId
         
     }).ToList());
```